Using transistor instead of analog switch
I am working on the following toggle circuit(Using 555) which toggles the output when the push button is pressed each time. Now, I want to replace the push button with a transistor (anything, BJT or MOSFET) to control it via a digital input, say an Arduino pin. There are analog switch ICs available, but I would like to know whether it is possible to do the switching with a transistor. If not, it would be great if you could explain why. I am also attaching the Falstad link for your reference.


If you have a Arduino, why would you use that circuit? Just incorporate all that functionality in code...

Even if you want to use the 555 with an Arduino, you shouldn't need a transistor.  You have a 555 in bistable mode.   Read one of the many tutorials on the 555, paying attention to that mode.

I don't have Arduino, I have a pin from another subsystem which will turn (ON)-OFF according to an external event. I mentioned Arduino for easiness.

If you have a pulse coming from another circuit, just use an ordinary flip-flop to get the toggle action.

The (ideal) switch in your circuit must switch the voltages Vcc to Vcc/2 or 0V to Vcc/2 depending on OUT.
A transistor is not an ideal switch in that it can not switch 2 different polarities.
So it might be possible but it would be not easy to do this with a transistor.
